# Using the array result of a select statement returns ERROR: pq: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]

Tags: postgresql, query, errors, array

The query in question is the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM options WHERE id = any(SELECT option_ids FROM workshops WHERE id=3)
```

```
ERROR: pq: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
```

Basically the statement inside any() returns an array of ids which I want to use to get some rows on the options table.

I don't understand why is it trying to compare an integer to the whole array, isnt any supposed to compare a single int to multiple integers in an array?

Answer (score 3):

You can unnest the array in order to create a valid statement, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM options WHERE id = any(SELECT unnest(option_ids) FROM workshops WHERE id=3);
```

Otherwise, if `id` is an `integer`, then the subquery inside of the `any` clause would need to return a column of integers (rather than a column of integer arrays) in order for the statement to be valid.

Comment: Nice. Other ideas. 2: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM workshops WHERE options.id = any(option_ids))`  3: `WHERE array[id] <@ any (SELECT option_ids FROM workshops)`